# Error in MVC 4 Application that uses OAuth in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor

I'm writing an MVC 4 Application that uses OAuth in Visual Studio 2012. I can compile without errors, but every time I run the application (previously working) I get the following error message.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest  definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

I haven't directly changed that package (System.Web.WebPages.Razor).

Comment: It seems that when you add oauth, it add previous version of System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Comment: Yeah, I was suspecting something like that. I checked the version of 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' in the project references (right click -> properties). It's still version 2.0.0.0.

And there's a line that says:


    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor"
    publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />

     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" 
     newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>

in web.config, I commented it but still no effect.

Comment: have you tried to create empty mvc4 app with oauth like here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc